# Most secure and flexible file access on a NAS

Tags: networking, nas, sftp, nfs, webdav

I have a NAS at home that I use to store my documents and media files.
I recently got a raspberry Pi on which I installed a media center (openElec).
Giving access to the media files to the raspberry was quite a nightmare.
I tried DLNA and NFS and they failed for some reasons that is not the point here.
Finally I succeeded using SFTP, and I wonder if this is a good idea.

Now I am wondering which protocol I should use for my different uses.

### Uses

My current and future uses are:

- File access from Windows PCs on local network (LAN and WiFi)
- File access from Windows PCs over internet
- Media center playing media files (movies, music, etc.)
- Backup of data between two NAS over internet
- Sharing data with family/friends (higher security and permission control needed)

### Protocols

So far I have seen:

- Windows File Service: used to map folders of the NAS
- FTP: abandoned since insecure
- SFTP: seams fine for external access
- Webdav: no idea
- NFS: No idea

### Equipment

I have 2 synology NAS. The main one is at my place. I use it to sync my data over multiple devices.
The second one will be in another location (I mean not at home).
I'll access it over internet to backup the main NAS.
And maybe to share data with family/friends.

### Questions

So finally my questions are:

- Which previously mentioned protocols can I use safely?
- Are there other interesting protocols?
- Which protocol suits best for the needs that I defined previously?

Just a precision, I manage the permission of the different folders individually (I mean using groups and *chmod*, or user by user). It may be needed for the answers.

I can understand that my question is not very accurate, but the problem is not very clear in my mind. I am not an IT guy!

Thanks for your help :)!

Comment: Can you provide more details about your NAS?  Any recommendation that your NAS can't implement would be wasted.

Comment: your uses imply different answers to your questions based on where the client is. LAN and WAN remote access are very different creatures afterall, and indicate a different set of protocols. for LAN WindowsFileSharing/Samba is more than sufficient and well supported for all your LAN purposes ( http://geeks.noeit.com/mount-an-smb-network-drive-on-raspberry-pi/ ). WAN access is somewhat more dangerous, and thus more difficult. As Andrew said, knowing what kind of NAS and what kind of Router you have will help us help you.

Comment: I added details about my equipment. I hope it'll be enough. Thanks for the suggestion. Regarding the raspberry Pi, I only use the settings available in OpenElec.I'll have a look if I can mount an SMB drive. Thanks again!

Comment: Since you use Synology NASs have you looked into QuickConnect: http://blog.synology.com/?p=2283 ? use Samba for access inside the lan, and QuickConnect for remote access. If you need on-the-fly video transcoding for less capable clients (phones, IoT devices) consider services like these: http://lifehacker.com/5975362/five-best-desktop-media-servers

Comment: Actually, I am trying to avoid QuickConnect. It sends everything to Synolgy servers, and I don't like the idea. More over, I use CloudStation from a LAN computer. I was setting up the syncing so I needed to transfer all files. I noticed that transfers where really slow. So I reconfigured it without QC and it was way faster. Regarding transcoding, do you advise me to install thos apps on the NAS itself? Thanks again!

Comment: A VPN server on the NAS/Router at your house and VPN clients on the remote NAS and other clients needing access covers all your requirements and is highly secure. Its the obvious answer here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't exactly know what a VPN is. From the user side, I know that companies usually provide external access to their employees thru  VPNs. But I don't know how it works. I have to look into that. Just one more question: is a VPN server something heavy for a synology NAS (213)? Thanks!